# Having issues with CSS and other scripts not loading after routing using nodeJs

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to make grab data from a MongoDb database and then viewing, editing and deleting it.

The first one is working pretty fine but what I am having issues with is editing. What I have done is made a route on a button click that basically works like this:

```
'/viewList/edit/'+item._id
```

This is supposed to take me to a form that will let me edit those values. The problem is that the CSS, Bootstrap and things like that break and the page looses all of the features they provide and it looks like a generic html that doesn't have any of these included in it.

If I remove the `"/edit/"` bit of the routing out and just do `'/viewList/'+item._id` it works.

I tested this by making a dummy page that tells details for that specific item like it's name and stuff and the page doesn't break, in terms of CSS/Bootstrap.

I really can't find a solution for this, can someone point in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to know without seeing what's in your `<head>` but the paths in your `<link>` tags are probably relative. This means they'll point to non-existent files when your URL path changes. Check that they start with `/` so your static file paths are always relative to the root URL rather than relative to the current page. i.e. if you have this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/styles.css">
```

Change it to:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/styles.css">
```